# chat inserting the data to the database but neither fetching the data from the database nor showing the content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, chat

I've putted my code here as formatting is 
The link given is the directory structure.
The problem I'm facing is that:
I'm creating a ajax chat application the data is going in the database. but meanwhile while I'm trying to retrieve that the data is not fetching. In some cases also happening that only user_id-2 data is fetched only.
I'm adding some screenshots here. 
[image]
The screenshot of My database are :
[image]
[image]
The links are given in the form of directory structure

[ajaxchat/index.php](http://www.codejaw.com/8mif9c)

[ajaxchat/js/chat.js](http://www.codejaw.com/8miiqg)

[ajaxchat/ajax/chat.php](http://www.codejaw.com/33sa6)

[ajaxchat/core/class/Chat.php](http://www.codejaw.com/8mikf8)

[ajaxchat/core/init.php](http://www.codejaw.com/v1uhw)

[ajax/core/class/Core.php](http://www.codejaw.com/v1ut5)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your sql has some errors, echo it, copy the output and then run it in phpmyadmin and see what happens

Comment: While I'm doing that it is giving an array of user = 2 values only  .